# Can't find project in run configuration in Eclipse after importing git repo

Tags: java, eclipse, egit

I have a remote repo that I've cloned using egit, and imported it into my workspace.  I want to run it, but when I go to the run configuration screen I don't see my project or my classes.

I've tried messing with the classpath, and deleted the workspace metadata and reimported.  No luck.

Does my build configuration need to be set up as well? I've tried setting that up a few different ways, all of which are throwing some kind of error.

What should I try next to get it to work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As a common practice, source control such as git are used to commit only source code and resources file. Eclipse project related files are not maintained in git repo ,as those may differ for different developers. So you don't get a run configuration when you import a git project.

In eclipse Run configuration is saved in file

```
yourWorkspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.debug.core\.launches
```

If you can get this file from other users, then you can save it in directory:

```
yourproject/.settings
```

Otherwise, I am afraid you will need to create a new Run Configuration